# Get the 't.co' short link for a twitter status using the API using Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, api, twitter

Using the Twitter API, I can get the `id_str` attribute of a status and make a link to a Twitter status like this:

```
function linkTweet(tweet){
  var linkToStatus = 'https://twitter.com/' + tweet.user.screen_name + '/status/' + tweet.id_str
  return linkToStatus
};
```

But, then I end up with a link that looks like this:

```
https://twitter.com/SomeLongUsername/status/702928587435450104
```

I need something like this:

```
https://t.co/LR4y0ahJkB
```

I can get external urls that are shortened to `'http://t.co/'` through `entities`, but is there a way to get a `t.co` formatted link to the status itself?

Comment: I'm looking for the exact same thing. Did you figure out a way to do this?

Comment: No, I had to find an alternative approach for what I was trying to do.